# What does it mean to travel without a visa?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, visa-free-entry

My passport allows me to travel to New Zealand without applying for a visa up to 90 days (3 months). But what does this mean? Should I buy the ticket immediately without taking into my consideration any sort of visa arrangements? And what if the immigration officer asked about what type of visa I have?

Answer (score 7):

> what does this mean?

It means you can visit the country without needing to get a visa before you travel.

> Should I buy the ticket immediately without taking into my consideration any sort of visa arrangements?

Yes.

> And what if the immigration officer asked about what type of visa I have?

You would say "I am from a [visa waiver country](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/visa-waiver-countries) as my passport shows, and I'll be staying for less than three months as my outbound ticket shows", and show them your passport and your outbound ticket. You'll also need to give them the arrivals card (a form) that you'll have completed on the plane (cabin crew will offer them to you).

More info:

> If you are in one of these groups, you are a ‘visa-waiver visitor’, and you do not need a visitor visa to travel to New Zealand. You need to apply for a visitor visa, but you will do this by completing an arrival card on the aircraft/ship on your way to New Zealand.
>
> You must also:
>
> - hold a valid ticket out of New Zealand to a country you have the right of entry to
> - have enough money to support yourself during your stay
> - hold a passport valid for three months beyond the date you are leaving New Zealand.
>
> The visa you are granted will allow a stay in New Zealand of no more than six months in a 12-month period. The 12-month period is calculated backwards from the last day you intend to be in New Zealand. For example, if you want to stay until 1 December 2014, you should count back 12 months, which would have been 1 December 2013.
>
> You must only visit New Zealand for the time granted to you on arrival. If you wish to visit for longer you will need to apply for another visitor
> visa. If you want to work, or study for longer than
> three months, in New Zealand you will have to
> apply for a work visa or a student visa.

[Visitor Visa Guide](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1018.pdf), New Zealand Immigration, August 2016

Comment: What if the visitor doesn't have a ticket out of New Zealand? It would be naive to book your ticket 3 months earlier. Will  Immigration New Zealand allow him/her to enter or not?

Comment: When the regulations say "must hold a valid ticket out of New Zealand" that would seem to be pretty clear. If you don't fulfil the rules, you might not be admitted. It would not be naive to book a ticket 3 months in advance. If you really don't know your return date, book a flexible ticket. But be aware that you will probably be granted a visa based on that return date.